# Pythonic way of filtering out a list of strings from another list of strings

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Still learning and have previously done this with nested loops but I was wondering if there was a pretty and condensed way of filtering out a list of strings from another list of strings.
I basically have a 300 column pandas dataframe and want to get rid of some columns from the dataframe if they have some key words. Then the plan is to specify the column titles to make a new dataframe.

Here are my attempts at list comprehension:

```
filter_array = ['hi', 'friend']
col_names = ['nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you' + 'friend']
p = [i for i in col_names if i not in filter_array]
print(p)
p = [i for i in col_names if e for e in filter_array e not in i]
print(p)
p = [i for i in col_names if e not in i for e in filter_array]
print(p)
```

The first attempt works but doesn't remove 'you+friend' where the filter word is present but exactly equal the col name so is kept.
My last attempt gives 'e is referenced before assignment'

Also why isn't there tag for pythonic! :)

Thanks guys and gals

Comment: Thank you for showing your attempts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this gets you the result you're looking for:

```
>>> filter_array = ['hi', 'friend']
>>> col_names = ['nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you' + 'friend']
>>>
>>> [c for c in col_names if all([f not in c for f in filter_array])]
['nice', 'to', 'meet']
```

It's worth noting (from the comments) that you can drop the inner `[]` in the call to `all` to change that inner list comprehension into a generator expression.  The list comprehension will use more memory, but will outperform a generator expression in the event that all steps of the generator must be consumed (when `all` can't shortcircuit).  You can also reverse the logic using `any` instead of `all`.  Ex:

```
>>> [c for c in col_names if all(f not in c for f in filter_array)]
['nice', 'to', 'meet']
>>> [c for c in col_names if not any(f in c for f in filter_array)]
['nice', 'to', 'meet']
```

Comment: You could also use `not any(f not in c for f in filter_array)` rather than putting the `not` in the comprehension. I also think using a generator expression rather than a list comprehension is worth while, since `all` or `any` will short circuit.

Comment: You're right - I've made note of both of those suggestions in the answer, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a more efficient way of doing this is to turn your list of tags into a `set()`

Then, you can do something like `filteredSet = setA - setB`, which will result in a copy of setA with the elements in setB removed from it.

Comment: Just changing to sets isn't going to do anything to deal with the substring matching he's requesting help with.